# Check if filter exists

Tags: python, python-jira

I am using jira-python with Python 2.7 and Jira Server to set up components and filters. I want to add new filters when needed and update existing ones when applicable. From the non-progress of this request; [JRASERVER-36045](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-36045), I am not optimistic about the prospects of retrieving a list of existing (public) filters. I was however hoping that I would be able to use a Try/Except block to create a filter, like so:

```
try:
    jira.create_filter(name=name_of_filter, jql=filter_str)
except JIRAError:
    jira.update_filter(name=name_of_filter, jql=filter_str)
```

However, first of all, I get

> NameError: name 'JIRAError' is not defined

What error type should I use?

Second; I think I need to provide a filter-ID instead of name to update it. But can I somehow get hold of the filter ID if I know the filter name?

Answer (score 1):

To you first question: you will need to import `JIRAError` to use it.  Something more like:

```
from jira import JIRA
from jira import JIRAError
jira = JIRA('https://jira.atlassian.com')

try:
    jira.create_filter(name=name_of_filter, jql=filter_str)
except JIRAError:
    jira.update_filter(name=name_of_filter, jql=filter_str)
```

Comment: Thanks'. That did it! Now I just need to figure out the second part.